# Emacs: How to split, open shell in bottom window at launch?

Tags: emacs

I tried adding this snippet to my `~/.emacs`, but the resulting buffer/window mapping is weird.

```
;; Open split shell on launch
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
  (lambda ()
    (let ((w (split-window-below 2)))
      (select-window w)
      (sh))
      (switch-to-buffer "*shell*")))
```

Example:

```
$ emacs .
```

Expected:

- top window is dired
- bottom window is shell

Observed:

- top window is scratch
- bottom window is dired

Comment: My suggestion would be to make a new function to create a noselect shell buffer that is not displayed in any particular window, and then display it wherever you want using something like `my-display-buffer`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19858/2287  To locate the shell buffer function, just type:  `M-x find-function RET shell RET`  The `pop-to-buffer` is what is causing your difficulties, similar to what the poster suffered from in the above-mentioned link.  If the area of code that follows `pop-to-buffer` requires that the `*shell*` buffer be set, consider using `with-current-buffer`.

Comment: You may also wish to look at the `emacs-startup-hook` to let Emacs `startup.el` finish its nonsense, and then you can go about your business.  Trying to go about your business before the nonsense ends will eventually make you learn how to create your own custom `startup.el` when building Emacs.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @lawlist:

```
;; Open split shell on launch
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (let ((w (split-window-below 2)))
      (select-window w)
      (sh))
      (switch-to-buffer "*shell*")))
```

Comment: for some reason, it opens 3 buffers (identical) of either the 'scratch' or of the file initially focused upon.

Comment: changing line 4 to 'split-window-below 1' helped.